# Laravel auth/login route not working in server but localhost

Tags: laravel-5.4, laravel-authorization

I am using laravel 5.4 default authentication system and it is working fine in localhost but when i upload my project to server, it is breaking. when i fill mail and password, it return back me 404 file not found error.
My site url is http://www.happycoder.me/imsRever2.0

Comment: You may want to look at this stack overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40278967/deploying-laravel-to-live-server on deploying Laravel to web hosts.  Where are you deploying too?

Comment: godaddy is my hosting provider

Comment: Answer below, more details writeup can be found on medium, search google for "laravel hosting on godaddy"

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure the .htaccess file as follows:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^imsRever2.0
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ imsRever2.0/$1 [L]
```

Otherwise, the main web server will not the routing, vs laravel causing the 404 error when the file isn't found.

Comment: if i add these lines to my htaccess file, it return me a 500 internal server  error .

Comment: 500 is an internal server error. Can you get the error from the log and post it?

Comment: i check my laravel.log file hosted in live server, it did'nt write any current log.all logs are looking old. see below                                                   
#52 G:\Xampp\htdocs\imsRever2.0\public\index.php(53): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#53 G:\Xampp\htdocs\imsRever2.0\server.php(21): require_once('G:\\Xampp\\htdocs...')

Answer (score 0):

My htaccess file is below what things i need to change

Options -MultiViews

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```